# Se casó en primeras nupcias

Tags: gramática

Entiendo que la palabra “[nupcias](https://dle.rae.es/nupcias)” es plural, pero me suena raro decir “se casó en primeras nupcias” - es como decir que se casó una y otra vez, cada vez siendo su primera boda ... ¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano!

Comment: Curiosamente dos palabras relacionadas con el casamiento no permiten el uso del singular: _nupcias_ y _esponsales_. Y por otro lado la palabra _boda_ deriva del latín "vota", que es un plural, significa "los votos".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como en muchos otros casos de sustantivos que provienen del latín, *nupcias* se escribe en su forma plural en todos los casos. Es decir, que permanece **invariable**.

Precisamente por su carácter de **sustantivo invariable**, no puede usarse la forma "nupcia". Y así queda atestiguado en el Diccionario:

> **nupcias**
> Del lat. nuptiae.
>
> 1. f. pl. Casamiento o boda.

Comment: [Acá](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Palabras_invariables_en_plural) hay más ejemplos de plurales invariables, _pluralia tantum_,  como añicos y fauces.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando alguien se desposa por primera vez, se dice normalmente que contrae "Primeras Nupcias".

La palabra nupcias es un cultismo que procede del latín, de la voz "nuptiae - iarum", empleada ya como plural desde la época romana y que básicamente hacia alusión a la "ceremonia de la boda" y aunque se utiliza en plural, "Primae nuptiae", esto remite a varios aspectos.

Por una parte, el plural hacia referencia de forma general a los varios días que duraba la boda y de forma particular al primer día de la misma, "primum nuptiarum dies" (primer día entre varios), en el sentido de la propia celebración, y por otro, ese plural trataba del matrimonio y de la unión de los dos esponsales, ya que al ser dos, marido y mujer, "Primeras Nupcias", la boda, era entendida como la realizada tanto desde la parte del futuro marido, como desde la parte de la futura esposa, su primera boda por parte de los dos, "Primeras Bodas", y desde este punto de vista para ambas partes era su primera vez (en plural, "unas Primeras Veces, Primerizas Bodas, Primeros Casamientos").

Cuando la persona desea casarse de nuevo, antes de volver a contraer matrimonio, primero es necesario poseer el status civil de soltero, separado o viudo, intentando con ello evitar que se produzcan casos de bigamia, considerada habitualmente como delito. En estos casos, de "segundo casamiento" y por aquella misma tradición, recibe igualmente el nombre de "Segundas Nupcias" "Nuptiae Secundae" y no "Segunda Nupcia". Para entender igualmente el proceso, como en el caso de las, "Primeras Nupcias", pondremos de ejemplo, el caso de dos viudos, así para el novio viudo, este nuevo casamiento, sería su segunda vez y en el caso de la novia viuda, este nuevo casamiento, también sería su segunda vez, así para los dos, tomados como un conjunto en que cada uno aporta la visión de su propio casamiento, serían éstas sus "Segundas Veces", "Segundas Nupcias", sus "Segundos Casamientos". Para la Iglesia de los primeros siglos de la Edad Media, estas "Nuptiae Secundae", "Segundas Nupcias", fueron consideradas un hecho infame y deshonroso que se prefería evitar, existiendo una prohibición, en segundas nupcias para la bendición nupcial, pues se entendía que solo las "Primeras Nupcias", eran las que propiamente habían sido bendecidas por el Señor.

Por otra parte, el latín para referirse al matrimonio como vínculo jurídico utiliza términos como "Connubium" o "Iustae Nuptiae" (Justas Nupcias). Estas figuras eran consideradas como un negocio jurídico solemne, por el que hombre y mujer se unían en una relación que tenía efectos civiles y religiosos, siendo el objeto principal de esa unión el de conformar una familia.

P.D. En Español, esto ha dado lugar a otro tipo de frases curiosas en plural, como "primeras veces", "primeros momentos", "primeros encuentros"... que no son entendidas del todo bien fuera del Español, pues en otros idiomas solo hay una "primera vez", un "primer momento" o un "primer encuentro", del que parte la acción que se quiere expresar en adelante, haciendo difícil entender la pluralidad para referirse a un hecho que nace desde una forma concreta.

Comment: Sobre la 1 cuestión fue error mío, como nota en el caso de soltero " El estado civil de soltero denota una aparente incongruencia como antecedente de las segundas nupcias, ya que para estar casado por 2 vez necesariamente ha de haber tenido el estado de casado con anterioridad. La soltería previa como antecedente de una segunda nupcia toma sentido si quien estuvo casado precedentemente solicitó la nulidad de su matrimonio, declarándosele tal. El efecto propio de la nulidad matrimonial es que deja a las partes en el mismo estado en que se encontraban antes de contraer matrimonio, como soltero".

Comment: En la segunda cuestión, es a partir del S. IX cuando se introducen localmente ciertas costumbres que permitan la bendición nupcial, al menos para uno de los cónyuges. Fuente principal, " La prohibición de velaciones en segundas nupcias: Legislación, Doctrina y Praxis. Joaquín Sedano Rueda. Universidad de Navarra."

Comment: "El estigma de impureza... en el Derecho clásico de la Iglesia quedó  plasmado tanto en el Decreto de Graciano...como en las Decretales de Gregorio IX, bajo el Título De secundis nuptiis... recogian decretales de Alejandro III y de Urbano III". Sobre los Papas; Alejandro III, de nombre secular Rolando Bandinelli, fue el 170.° Papa de la Iglesia Católica desde el 7 de Septiembre de 1159 hasta su muerte en 1181. Urbano III. Papa número 172 de la Iglesia Católica desde el año 1185 al 1187.​

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones!

Comment: ¡Gracias a usted!